# Add support for XPATH replace in JCR (Jackrabbit Oak)

Tags: xpath, aem, jackrabbit-oak

I'm trying to determine if there's a way to create a custom [`Predicate`](https://www.adobe.io/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/index.html?com/day/cq/search/Predicate.html) to handle searches for text that contains accented characters.

The problem I am trying to solve is that I have the string "Montréal" stored in the JCR, and want it to show up if my query contains a search for "Montreal" or even "Montre".

I am trying to use the XPATH function [`fn:replace`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_replace.html) to do something like this:

```
replace('Montréal', '[éè]+', 'e')
```

Here's an example xpath query (run using the query tool in the CRX/DE):

```
/jcr:root/content/dam/mysite/en//*
[
(@jcr:primaryType = 'dam:AssetContent' and jcr:like(fn:replace(fn:lower-case(data/master/@city), '[éè]+', 'e'),'%montre%'))
]
```

However, when I attempt to use it, I get the error:

```
expected: jcr:like | jcr:contains | jcr:score | xs:dateTime | fn:lower-case | fn:upper-case | fn:name | rep:similar | rep:spellcheck | rep:suggest
```

Is there some way to enable the replace function?

Comment: Since you’re using Oak, it would seem creating a [Lucene Full-Text Index](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html) on the relevant properties would be a better solution. Lucene indices are very versatile and can be configured with all sorts of normalization options for diacritics and other special chars.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert thank you for the response - do you have any broad direction for a Lucene based implementation? My first thought would be to use [function based indexing](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html#function-based-indexing) but the list of supported functions is the same. Other indexing features appear to be mostly stateless and I don't see a property that would help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue.

I will explain what I did to overcome that.

**The requirement** : There is a search bar, and in that user were using accented chars.

**The problem** : same. jcr:like & fn:replace didn't work.

What I did was, sent the search param as it is intp the backend (Java) through servlet, as I was building queries through a service there.
Then I just encoded them in base64, and added the same in the query, as AEM keeps non-english chars in base64 encoded values.

Then just decoded the results in the FE ( but you can do that in Java as well.)